# Can I store MediaPlaybackItem in SQLite ?

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I want to store MediaPlaybackItem data type in SQLite for future purpose. Can I really do that? If so what will be the column type?

Comment: I would suggest to save the media URI to SQLite and then create MediaPlaybackItem again from that URI when needed. If that doesn't fit for you maybe you can give your use case, can suggest a better option based on it.

Comment: Thanks. Can entity framework store it?

Comment: Of course, It's just a string. You can use EF for it.

Comment: I want to store MediaPlaybackItem in EF database. can I do that?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible.